# I cannot able to curl different images in Page based application using StoryBoard(iOS5)

Tags: ios5, storyboard

I am using story board to create a page based application. When I run my app, I can curl the same image in every page. But I want to curl with different images when I curl a page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you offer more detail about what you've tried already?

Have you already implemented UIPageViewControllerDataSource?  This is where you would write your "viewControllerBeforeViewController" and "viewControllerAfterViewController" methods.  Once you write those methods, you should be able to move from one page to another.  If you look at the project template included in Xcode, there's an example of this in the "ModelController" class.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have implemented the data source. The page curl effect is working. But,all pages are fetching same images when curled. Could you please help me out in writing the code to implement the array of images in the page curl template in iOS5 using storyboard.

Comment: Go ahead and post your current code for 'before' and 'after'.  I'll see if I can help you out.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSLog(@"Detail view");
  
   NSArray *img = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"WEEK100002.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"AngelandSatan.png"],
                   nil];

 //img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"WEEK10001.png"];     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}